# Finding non trivial Idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra

$A$ = the group algebra of the symmetric group $S_2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Find a nontrivial idempotent within $A$

So:

I let $S_2 = (e,s)$. I understand that for $a \in A$ I need to find

$a^2 = a$ for $a = \alpha x_e + \beta x_s$. Clearly $\alpha = \beta = 0$ works. I am confused on how to find a $nontrivial$ idempotent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially solve $(ax_{e} + bx_{s})^{2} = ax_{e} +bx_{s}$. On the left hand side we get $(a^{2} + b^{2})x_{e} + 2ab x_{s} = a x_{e} + b x_{s}$. Since we want non trivial solutions $a = 1/2$ and $b = 1/2$.

Comment: $(x_e+x_s)^2=2(x_e+x_s)$ so you need the factor $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry my phone was acting funny. Fixed the formatting and answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a group $G$ and a field $k$ of characteristic prime to $|G|$, there is always the idempotent $$x=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_G x_g$$ in the group algebra $kG$ (check that it is indeed an idempotent). In the special case $G=S_2$, this is $x=\frac{1}{2}(x_e+x_s)$. Actually, you can prove that $x$ and $1-x$ are the only primitive idempotents of $\Bbb{Q}S_2$.